# Simple hashing code with excessive conditional statements

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, console

Any thoughts on my code? It's a simple hashing code that runs from the command line.

There just appears to be a lot of condition `if` / `elif` entries in both of the main functions (`hashingmethod` and `hashcalculator`).

```
# hashcalculator.py

import sys
import hashlib


args = len(sys.argv)

def inputVerification():
    if sys.argv[1] == "--help":
        scriptHelp()
    elif args < 5:
        print "You have failed to execute the command correctly"
        print "Please type 'hashcalculator --help' for more information"
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[2]
        hashingMethod(filename)

def scriptHelp():
    print "\n"
    print "----------------------------------------"
    print "\tWelcome to Hash Calculator"
    print "----------------------------------------"
    print "\n"
    print "--help"
    print "\n"
    print "In order to calculate the hash value of a file, your command line syntax"
    print "must be written as below:-"
    print "\n"
    print "\thashcalculator -f [file] -h [hash method]"
    print "\teg. hashcalculator -f notepad.exe -h SHA1"
    print "\n"
    print "The recognised hashing methods are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512" 

def hashingMethod(filename):
    hashmethod = sys.argv[4].upper()
    if hashmethod == "MD5":
        hashCalculator(filename, "md5")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA1":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha1")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA224":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha224")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA256":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha256")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA384":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha384")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA512":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha512")
    else:
        print "You have not entered a valid hashing method"
        print "Please review the help document"
        scriptHelp()

def hashCalculator(filename, hashmethod):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if hashmethod == "md5":
            m = hashlib.md5()
        elif hashmethod == "sha1":
            m = hashlib.sha1()
        elif hashmethod == "sha224":
            m = hashlib.sha224()
        elif hashmethod == "sha256":
            m = hashlib.sha256()
        elif hashmethod == "sha384":
            m = hashlib.sha384()
        elif hashmethod == "sha512":
            m = hashlib.sha512()
        else:
            scriptHelp()
        while True:
            data = f.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
        print "\n\n"
        print "The %s hash of file %s is:" % (hashmethod.upper(), filename)
        print "\n", m.hexdigest()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputVerification()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should really take a look at [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html): *the argparse module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces*. It will even take care of writing the help for you.

Even if you will apply very little of the following (since you should really use the `argparse` module), I'll give you some advice anyway.

### [`str.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

This:

```
if hashmethod == "MD5":
    hashCalculator(filename, "md5")
elif hashmethod == "SHA1":
    hashCalculator(filename, "sha1")
elif hashmethod == "SHA224":
    hashCalculator(filename, "sha224")
elif hashmethod == "SHA256":
    hashCalculator(filename, "sha256")
elif hashmethod == "SHA384":
    hashCalculator(filename, "sha384")
elif hashmethod == "SHA512":
    hashCalculator(filename, "sha512")
```

could just be:

```
hashCalculator(filename, hashmethod.lower())
```

### Coding style

Follow the official coding style, the main rules are summarized [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/495/10415).

### [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)

This:

```
if hashmethod == "md5":
    m = hashlib.md5()
elif hashmethod == "sha1":
    m = hashlib.sha1()
elif hashmethod == "sha224":
    m = hashlib.sha224()
elif hashmethod == "sha256":
    m = hashlib.sha256()
elif hashmethod == "sha384":
    m = hashlib.sha384()
elif hashmethod == "sha512":
    m = hashlib.sha512()
```

could just be:

```
m = getattr(hashlib, hashmethod)
```

### Multiple line strings

Don't do this:

```
print "\n"
print "----------------------------------------"
print "\tWelcome to Hash Calculator"
print "----------------------------------------"
print "\n"
print "--help"
print "\n"
print "In order to calculate the hash value of a file, your command line syntax"
print "must be written as below:-"
print "\n"
print "\thashcalculator -f [file] -h [hash method]"
print "\teg. hashcalculator -f notepad.exe -h SHA1"
print "\n"
print "The recognised hashing methods are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512"
```

Do this instead:

```
msg = """
----------------------------------------
\tWelcome to Hash Calculator
----------------------------------------

--help

In order to calculate the hash value of a file, your command line syntax
must be written as below:-
\thashcalculator -f [file] -h [hash method]
\teg. hashcalculator -f notepad.exe -h SHA1

The recognised hashing methods are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512"""

print msg
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rik. Some really good pointers made and some really obvious oversights on my behalf!!

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import hashlib


args = len(sys.argv)
```

You don't really get anything by doing this. You only use it once. Just use `len(sys.argv)` instead of `args`.

```
def inputVerification():
```

Python convention is to have lowercase_with_underscores

```
    if sys.argv[1] == "--help":
        scriptHelp()
```

What if the user passed no arguments? This will fail.

```
    elif args < 5:
        print "You have failed to execute the command correctly"
        print "Please type 'hashcalculator --help' for more information"
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[2]
        hashingMethod(filename)
```

Don't call the next function at the end of the function. You should return the filename from this function and then call hashingMethod in the caller.

```
def scriptHelp():
    print "\n"
    print "----------------------------------------"
    print "\tWelcome to Hash Calculator"
    print "----------------------------------------"
    print "\n"
    print "--help"
    print "\n"
    print "In order to calculate the hash value of a file, your command line syntax"
    print "must be written as below:-"
    print "\n"
    print "\thashcalculator -f [file] -h [hash method]"
    print "\teg. hashcalculator -f notepad.exe -h SHA1"
    print "\n"
    print "The recognised hashing methods are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512"
```

You should this in a multiline string rather then lots of print statements.

```
def hashingMethod(filename):
    hashmethod = sys.argv[4].upper()
    if hashmethod == "MD5":
        hashCalculator(filename, "md5")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA1":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha1")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA224":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha224")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA256":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha256")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA384":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha384")
    elif hashmethod == "SHA512":
        hashCalculator(filename, "sha512")
    else:
        print "You have not entered a valid hashing method"
        print "Please review the help document"
        scriptHelp()
```

Instead of chains of IFs, put your supported methods in a list.

```
def hashCalculator(filename, hashmethod):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if hashmethod == "md5":
            m = hashlib.md5()
        elif hashmethod == "sha1":
            m = hashlib.sha1()
        elif hashmethod == "sha224":
            m = hashlib.sha224()
        elif hashmethod == "sha256":
            m = hashlib.sha256()
        elif hashmethod == "sha384":
            m = hashlib.sha384()
        elif hashmethod == "sha512":
            m = hashlib.sha512()
        else:
            scriptHelp()
```

Instead of doing this, I'd suggest using a dictionary

```
        while True:
            data = f.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)

        print "\n\n"
        print "The %s hash of file %s is:" % (hashmethod.upper(), filename)
        print "\n", m.hexdigest()
```

Don't mix your output with your logic.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputVerification()
```

You only seem to read a few random entries from sys.argv. You don't look at argv[3] at all. You only pay attention if argv[1] is "--help".

Here's me reworking of your code:

```
import sys
import hashlib

HASH_METHODS = {
    'md5' : hashlib.md5,
    'sha1' : hashlib.sha1,
    'sha224' : hashlib.sha224,
    'sha256' : hashlib.sha256,
    'sha384' : hashlib.sha384,
    'sha512' : hashlib.sha512
}

USAGE = """

----------------------------------------
\tWelcome to Hash Calculator
----------------------------------------

--help

In order to calculate the hash value of a file, your command line syntax
must be written as below:-


hashcalculator -f [file] -h [hash method]
\teg. hashcalculator -f notepad.exe -h SHA1


The recognised hashing methods are MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384 and SHA512
"""

def hash_file(method, filename):
    m = method()
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(8192)
            if not data:
                break
            m.update(data)
    return m.hexdigest()

def show_script_help():
    print USAGE


def main(args):
    if args[1:] == ['--help']:
        show_script_help()
    elif len(args) != 3:
        print "You have failed to execute the command correctly"
        print "Please type 'hashcalculator --help' for more information"
    else:
        filename, hash_method = sys.argv[1:]

        try:
            method = HASH_METHODS[hash_method]
        except KeyError:
            print "You have not entered a valid hashing method"
            print "Please review the help document"
        else:
            hashed = hash_file(method, filename)
            print "\n\n"
            print "The %s hash of file %s is:" % (hash_method.upper(), filename)
            print "\n", hashed



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the advice @Winston. Much appreciate and thanks for the time in assisting me and reviewing my code. Some really good points made.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python developer, so this might be completely missing the point. But I look at the [code for hashlib.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/hashlib.py). And there is a chunk of code in the middle that looks a lot like yours, so I wonder if you're reinventing the wheel.

Looking further at the [documentation for hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) and it looks like it has a constructor which takes the name and returns a hashing object.

So you should be able to replace half of your code with a simple

```
m = hashlib.new(hashmethod)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the comments @pdr. The reason behind me creating this code is to simply practice coding in Python. There are quite a few hash calculators out there written in Python but I was just looking to start from scratch to learn as I go along.